# Jaeger-all-in-one.exe redirect logging to file

Tags: c#, open-telemetry, jaeger, otel

I have a setup that writes spans to an otel collector, which then sends them to Jaeger.
The entire thing has a wrapper around it that starts the applications in a windows environment.

This works fine, but now I want to redirect the startup logging of Jaeger to a file, to see what goes wrong if Jaeger does not start. I am not looking to write the spans that it logs to a file, just the startup of Jaeger itself.

This is the code I've tried, but my file is always empty:

```
// Create a new process instance for the command prompt
    Process process = new Process();

    // Set the file name and arguments for the process (cmd.exe)
    process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/C jaeger-all-in-one.exe"; // Add any additional arguments here

    // Enable output redirection
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

    // Create files to redirect the output and error streams to
    string outputFilePath = @"C:\temp\output.txt";
    string errorFilePath = "error.txt";
    process.StartInfo.StandardOutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
    process.StartInfo.StandardErrorEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

    using (StreamWriter outputFile = new StreamWriter(outputFilePath))
    using (StreamWriter errorFile = new StreamWriter(errorFilePath))
    {
        // Attach event handlers to capture the output and error streams
        process.OutputDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data))
            {
                // Write the output to the file
                outputFile.WriteLine(e.Data);
            }
        };

        process.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data))
            {
                // Write the error to the file
                errorFile.WriteLine(e.Data);
            }
        };

        // Start the process
        process.Start();

        // Begin asynchronous read operations on the output and error streams
        process.BeginOutputReadLine();
        process.BeginErrorReadLine();

        // Continue with the rest of your code execution

        Console.WriteLine("Process started. Output will be saved to: " + outputFilePath);
        Console.WriteLine("Errors will be saved to: " + errorFilePath);

        // Wait for user input to stop the process
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to stop the process...");
        Console.ReadKey();

        // Stop the process
        try
        {
            process.Kill();

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }

        // Close the output and error files
        outputFile.Close();
        errorFile.Close();
    }

    // Display a message indicating that the process has been stopped
    Console.WriteLine("Process stopped. Output saved to: " + outputFilePath);
    Console.WriteLine("Errors saved to: " + errorFilePath);
```